# Activity Destroy method gets called on long pressing device home?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have an activity called login,when login screen gets visible to me I press home key due to which app goes in background state,and again after few min when I press long device home key then I saw log showing Login activity ondestroy() called and when open app from pressing home button it starts from splash screen,this will occurs for only to this particular activity.

code:-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce)
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        CSplashScreen.this.finish();;
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.pressagaintoexit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    },2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the Home switches you from the app to the home screen, whilst leaving your app running in the background. This is a bit like switching between windows on a Windows PC.

Except that when your phone is running low on resources like memory it will start to close apps that are running in the background, so that your phone has enough resources for what you're trying to do now. Games are often amongst the first apps the phone will "kill" to save resources as they often use a lot more memory and CPU than other apps. This is why sometimes your game is still running paused, and sometimes Android has closed it for you.

The Back button is the way to close apps so that they are actually closed.